# Using Triggers for UPDATE Tables MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a TEMP table that is fed data using a Stored Proc when the table is shown through the website. This works great. I have this table as an editable one so that if/when the data in this table is edited then it will send the updated data back to my TEMP table, again this updates as it should. I now have a Trigger that will take certain fields from the TEMP and update my LIVE db table.

My problem is that when I add in other fields to update based on what is UPDATED it will do so for each row within the TEMP table. I have tried various ways, below being my last attempt to just update that particular row.

```
CREATE 
DEFINER = 'user'@'%'
    TRIGGER update_epcplanneddate
AFTER UPDATE
ON ims.temp_tobebooked
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
 UPDATE epc_planning p
  INNER JOIN temp_tobebooked b ON b.PropID = p.PropID
 SET
  p.EPCStatus = CASE WHEN p.PropID = b.PropID THEN 3 END, 
  p.EPCPlannedDate = b.EPCPlannedDate,
  p.EPCBookingDate = CASE WHEN p.PropID = b.PropID THEN NOW() END,
  p.LastUpdateDate = CASE WHEN p.PropID = b.PropID THEN NOW() END,
  p.LastUpdateUser = b.InputBy
 WHERE p.PropID = b.PropID;
END
```

How can I update what I need to update along with the extra fields based on this UPDATE?

Comment: Don't use a JOIN, use `NEW.column` to get the value from the updated row in the temp table.

Comment: Ok, so the Trigger would now look like this? `CREATE 
 DEFINER = 'user'@'%'
TRIGGER update_epcplanneddate
 AFTER UPDATE
 ON temp_tobebooked
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     UPDATE epc_planning p      
     SET
      p.EPCStatus = 3, 
      p.EPCPlannedDate = NEW.EPCPlannedDate,
      p.EPCBookingDate = NOW(),
      p.LastUpdateDate = NOW(),
      p.LastUpdateUser = NEW.InputBy
     WHERE p.PropID = NEW.PropID;
END`

Comment: Sounds about right, I think.

Comment: @user3473593: Why don't you post your comment as an answer!!

Comment: Thanks, works a treat, I've not used Triggers before so the NEW.column was all new to me.

Answer (score 0):

So changing the JOIN to using NEW.colum the Trigger now looks like this

```
CREATE 
DEFINER = 'user'@'%'
    TRIGGER update_epcplanneddate
AFTER UPDATE
ON temp_tobebooked
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
 UPDATE epc_planning p      
 SET
  p.EPCStatus = 3, 
  p.EPCPlannedDate = NEW.EPCPlannedDate,
  p.EPCBookingDate = NOW(),
  p.LastUpdateDate = NOW(),
  p.LastUpdateUser = NEW.InputBy
 WHERE p.PropID = NEW.PropID;
END
```